# Category header imports not working

Tags: objective-c, categories, objective-c-category

I have a workspace that has two projects in it.  The first project was essentially a test and develop project where I got things working before worrying about tying everything together for real.  The second project is bringing all my individually developed view controllers together in a storyboard.

On one of the view controllers I have a bunch of swipe gestures with quite a bit of UIView animation calls nicely formatted for readability and therefore taking a lot of space.  I elected to move them out as a category.

The problem is that the compiler is not seeing the instance variable declarations in the main header file.

What has me pulling my hair out is that I did this in the first project and it all worked fine.  So I'm carefully comparing the contents of my second project to the first and I see no differences.

Here're some file snippets to help demonstrate how/where I'm defining things, and then snippets of code in the category file that is attempting to access them:

GSBViewController.h

```
@interface GSBViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *roundPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *roundsSectionView;
```

GSBViewController.m

```
#import "GSBViewController+Swipe.h"

@interface GSBGameBuilderViewController ()
{
    UIBarButtonItem *rightGatherBarButton;

    NSInteger previousRound;
}
@end

@implementation GSBViewController
@synthesize roundPicker;
@synthesize roundsSectionView;
```

GSBViewController+Swipe.h

```
#import "GSBViewController.h"

@interface GSBViewController (Swipe)

- (void)establishSwipeGestures;

@end
```

GSBViewController+Swipe.m

```
#import "GSBViewController+Swipe.h"

@implementation GSBViewController (Swipe)

- (void)establishSwipeGestures
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = 
       [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
           initWithTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(roundsSectionLeft:)];

    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [roundsSectionView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
// bunch-o-code snipped -- for the time being it's actually all commented out
// as a test and because the LLVM compiler was giving up after too many errors
// and I wanted to see if there was more it would like to tell me about this first --
// and very representative -- problem.
}
@end
```

The complaint from the compiler is "Use of undeclared identifier 'roundsSectionView'"

If I option-click on the use of roundsSectionView in that line of code where I'm adding the gesture recognizer to it the pop-up correctly describes it as declared in GSBViewController.h

So I'm stumped.

Is there something I can do in Xcode (4.3.2 at the time of this posting :-) to let me see what the included files are?   Or is there something non-file-based that is needed to tie a category into the class it's augmenting?  I don't remember anything like that being necessary before.  In fact, the way I generated the files for this category was through Xcode's File -> New File... Objective-C Category template.  Then I just copied the contents of the old ...+Swipe.h and ...+Swipe.m files and pasted them into their respective files in the new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Jacques Cousteau says is correct.

Since you just defined a property and no backing ivar, the category won't be able to access it. If you use `self.roundsSectionView` it will use the getter method generated for the property and hence it will work.

Or you could define a backing variable in your interface

```
@interface GSBViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIBarButtonItem *roundsSectionView;
}
```

In this case the categories will be able to access the variable. But not any other class.

Comment: Thank you, chirag.  A closer look at my "old" code did show backing variables being defined for those variables.  And adding them to the "new" code satisfied the compiler.

Comment: Many people use the style `@synthesize aVariable = _aVariable;` -- Is that also creating a "backing ivar" for the property?

Comment: Yes. `@synthesize var = _anything_` creates a backing variable. `_varName` is just a convention so that you don't use `varName` instead of `self.varName` by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

A synthesized ivar is private. The compiler won't allow you to access it anywhere execept in the `@implementation` block where it's created. Neither categories nor subclasses can access the ivar directly; they must use the property: `[self roundsSectionView]`.

There's a slight possibilty that earlier Clangs didn't make synthesized ivars private. Either that or you weren't really doing exactly the same thing in the earlier project.

Comment: Thank you, too.  The differences between instance variables and properties is obviously one I struggle with.  I had thought a property was to be thought of as a property of the class, but there clearly are deeper nuances.  Hopefully my question here will guide others to your answer and that of @chirag too.

Comment: In my world view whatever works is right. And your answer appears right when I compile my code ;-)  But in reading the Apple documentation on Declared Properties I don't see it mentioned that synthesized ivars are private.  At least not in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW13